# Joomla 3 Custom Inquiry Form Module

Tags: php, email, content-management-system, joomla3.0

I've tried to create simple module where I created a inquiry form with attachment. The basics are there however I'm stuck on what will be the form action and how can I handle the form inputs to sent as email. I have no plans on saving it to the database. The purpose is when user fill out the form and send it, the email marketer will receive it as an email. Below are my codes.

mod_inquire.php

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php';
$inquire = modMessageHelper::getInquire($params);
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_inquire');
```

mod_inquire.xml

```
<extension type="module" version="3.1.0" client="site" method="upgrade">
<name>Inquire Here</name>
<author>John Doenut</author>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<description>A simple Inquiry module.</description>
<files>
    <filename module="mod_message">mod_inquire.php</filename>
    <folder>tmpl</folder>
    <filename>helper.php</filename>
</files>
<config>
</config>
</extension>
```

helper.php

```
class ModInquireHelper{  
public static function getInquire($params){
    return "Inquiry!";
}
}
```

default.php

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

?>
<div class="container-fluid">
<form action="" method="post" id="inquiry-form" class="form-inline" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inquiry-name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inquiry-name" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
        <label for="inquiry-email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inquiry-email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inquiry-message">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="inquiry-message" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inquiry-attachment">Attach a file</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="inquiry-attachment">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Questions:

1. How do I passed and process the form inquiry?
2. How do I attach a file?
3. What will be my form action?

If there are similar questions and answers about this, let me know. Also, If there are tutorials you can send the links and if you can directly answer my question, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use one of the ready made forms from extensions directory? It's much easier than code your own.
[link here](https://extensions.joomla.org/category/contacts-and-feedback/forms/)